# Xcode complaining the building could produce unreliable result.

Tags: xcode10

I got the Xcode, the info. plist file could not be found. "Build input file cannot be found" . So I added the info.plist file . And now I am getting this error that the building could produce unreliable result. I have also added AVFoundationFramework which I am using in the app. Attaching screenshot for the clearance. 
[image]

[image]

added the framework

[image: adding this as well]

only to get this warning of duplication , in the first it is required isn't it . 
[image: duplicate warning]

So how to solve this error ? 
[image: cycle error]

Note:  I have renamed my project name, which I thought the reason behind the missing .plist so I added the .plist only to find the cycle error coming out of Xcode. Just need to know why it is happening. I am using Xcode 10.0 beta 2.

Answer (score 5):

`Xcode` - `File` - `Workspace Settings`

changed `Build System` to `Legacy Build System`

Knows these many, hoped that may help you, wishes the good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the Run script at last in the build phase, it was working fine